# Polynomial, bounded functional

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity, normed-spaces

In order to prove continuity of the functional $$\varphi: \mathbb{R}[X] \ni p \rightarrow p'(2011) \in \mathbb{R}$$ where $$||p|| = \sup \{|p(t), \ t\in [0,1]\}$$ I'd like to prove that this functional is bounded.

So I need to find an $M>0$ such that $|\varphi(p)| = |p'(t)| \le M ||p||$.

I thought that maybe I could use a Mean value theorem, but those theorems claim that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $p'(c)= \frac{p(b)-p(a)}{b-a}$, whereas in my problem $c=2011$ is already given?

How can I prove boundedness of this functional?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of the functional $\phi$, what is $x$? Is it a given number in $[0,1]$?

In any case.

This functional is not going to be bounded. Take $p(x)=x^n$ for example. We have $||p||=1$ but $p'(x)=nx^{n-1}$, which take the maximum value $p'(1)=n$ (assuming the $x$ in your definition of $\phi$ is $1$).

Examples like this can be constructed no matter what is $x$ in your definition of $\phi$.

Comment: So this functional is not continuous?

Comment: @Sasha Yes, the derivative of a small function can be large.